# Picasso in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

so I'm struggling to fully understand something about the Picasso library. If I type:

```
Picasso.get().load(file).fit().into(letterImage)
```

Does this mean that the the loading of the image gets done in a background thread, without blocking the main thread or do I have to create a thread and run this line of code within that thread?

Comment: Yes Picasso handle multithreading by itself you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Picasso or Glide handle threading itself, you have to just provide your image content to it.

Comment: I took a couple of minutes to try to figure it how they do it, but I couldn't the deepest I could see was Picasso is using OkHttp under the hood and that at some point should handle the threading, couldn't find specifically how.

Comment: Ok so even if I am just displaying images that are stored in the phones filesystem it does all the processing/loading in a background thread right?